# Can't .include relationship with ActiveRecord data when sending json_response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I need to get a response as such:

```
{ 
  unit_id: 5, 
  notifications: [
    {
      id: 123, 
      unit_id: 5, 
      created_at: 2020-01-24T16:42:20.000Z,
      grow_notification_id: 59: 
      grow_notification: {
        id: 59, 
        title: "Update 6.0.0",
        full_content: "Introducing fresh push notifications! We...",
        ...
      },
     ...
    ]
  }
}
```

I know I can do something `@unit.notifications.include(:grow_notifications)` but it is not giving me the desired format.

The only thing that somewhat worked was when I did:

```
@notifications = @unit.notifications
render json: @notifications.includes(:grow_notification), include: ['grow_notification']
```

But, if I try and do something like:

```
render json: {
  unit_id: @unit.id,
  notifications: @notifications.includes(:grow_notification), include: ['grow_notification']
}
```

or

```
render json: {
  unit_id: @unit.id,
  active_unit_plant: @unit.active_unit_plant,
  notifications: @notifications.includes(:grow_notification), include: ['grow_notification']
}
```

I am not getting the `.grow_notification` object in the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As reference usage of `render` [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render):

```
render(options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block)
```

Below code is not working because you put the `include: ['grow_notification']` into the first argument `options` when it should be the second `extra_options`

```
render json: {
  unit_id: @unit.id,
  notifications: @notifications.includes(:grow_notification), include: ['grow_notification']
}
```

Correct usage:

```
render json: {
  unit_id: @unit.id,
  notifications: @notifications
}, include: ['grow_notification']
```

Comment: Yes, I see I had the wrong syntax. I am actually trying to use `json_response` instead now, but the only thing I can find online is by scotch.io. Do you know, how I can do: `json_response({unit_id: @unit.id, notifications: @notifications.include(:grow_notification)})` with the `grow_notification: {}` blob?

Comment: Is `json_response` a separated gem feature?